# How to dynamically contruct / change a part of LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method in my app, which needs to read, filter, and serve up data, based on a set of criteria.
I'm trying to use LINQ to accomplish this:

```
var pipelineData = from data in new XPQuery<AccountView3.PipelineData>(uow)
         where data.Stage.ToLower().Contains("won")
         && data.RevenueStartDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Today.Year
         && data.WeekOfTheYear >= priorWeekCutoff
         && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.PlatformTcv) && data.PlatformTcv != "#N/A")
         select data;
```

By itself, this works just fine. The problem is - depending on the search criteria that is being passed, instead of data.PlatformTvc it may be data.WorkspaceTvc, or data.CyberTvc, etc...
I do not have a way of knowing in advance which of the possible 5 choices needs to be evaluated.

My question is: is there a way to construct a LINQ statement in such a way, that a part of the statement is conditionally executed. So if the user passes "Platform" as the search criteria, the LINQ statement would read ... `string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.PlatformTcv)`, but if the criteria is "Cyber", then this LINQ statement should read ... `string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.CyberTcv)`
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Take advantage of LINQs deferred execution model and embed a changeable predicate into the query. For example:

```
Func<DataObject, string> accessor = data => data.PlatformTcv;

var pipelineData = from data in new XPQuery<AccountView3.PipelineData>(uow)
                   where data.Stage.ToLower().Contains("won")
                       && data.RevenueStartDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Today.Year
                       && data.WeekOfTheYear >= priorWeekCutoff
                       && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessor(data))
                       && accessor(data) != "#N/A")
                   select data;

var basedOnPlatform = pipelineData.ToArray();

accessor = data => data.CyberTV;

var basedOnCyber = pipelineData.ToArray();
```

(This assumes the query element type is `DataObject`. Of course, you would replace that with the actual name of whatever type you're using).

Just remember that this will make the LINQ harder to understand, and always keep in mind the deferred-execution nature of your queries. I.e. if they aren't "materialized" as some other collection (e.g. calling `ToArray()`), then changes to the underlying query will show up the next time you execute it.

Comment: That was genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an IQueryable for the part that is the same for all queries:

```
var pipelineData = from data in new XPQuery<AccountView3.PipelineData>(uow)
     where data.Stage.ToLower().Contains("won");
     // etc
```

Then apply the specific filter:

```
if (somecondition) 
{
    pipelineData = pipelineData.Where(x => x.SomeField == "somevalue");
}
// etc
```

Comment: Careful. The OP _might_ want to reuse the original query (not entirely clear to me from the post), so you might not want to assign the new filtered version back to the original variable. It's worth noting that at least for the original example, this solution is likely to be a more readable, easier-to-maintain approach than the one I offered. It doesn't generalize to other elements of a LINQ query, but IMHO this is a very good choice if you're just doing filtering.